# perimeter/barrier/dam on thinset for self leveling compound

Tags: self-leveling-concrete, thinset

What product or methods can I use to create a perimeter/barrier/dam on thinset for self leveling compound in a doorway?  I'm pouring 300sf in sections as the SLC has limited working time.

[Thermostrips](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ThermoSoft-ThermoStrips-2-ft-x-2-in-x-3-8-in-Self-Leveling-Cement-Perimeter-Barrier-Edge-Strips-with-Self-Adhesive-12-strips-TS516-0248HD/203993106) won't work as the surface is not flat.  I could create a temporary barrier using spray foam or caulk, but it might be a pain to remove.  Is there a temporary product that would be easy to remove from thinset and SLC?

Comment: Some insight into your situation would be good. There's no one answer. Please post a better description or link a photo.

Comment: 300 sq/ft is a fairly small room, so the "in a doorway" comment doesn't make a lot of sense in that context. Pictures of the area to be filled would be best, but [edit]ing in more details would go a long way to helping us understand.

Comment: Also, I'm not certain why those Thermostrips _won't_ work, they look ideal. They're made out of "synthetic cork", so I'd think they'd be flexible, in case the floor is wavy. Maybe describe _why_ you don't think they'd work - nothing says that you have to fill the entire space to the top of the strip all the way around, just fill until you've got a level surface...

Comment: I don't have any help, so the plan is to break up the 300sf into manageable sections. When the tile was removed, it left a very rough surface. I don't see the Thermostrips creating a tight seal against the floor. How can I post a picture?